# Custom WPF TextBox with attached unit TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

My application has tons of `TextBox` controls where the user can enter numeric values. Most of these values are in some physical unit. This unit indicator is displayed at the right side of the `TextBox` control.

That looks like the following sketch: [________] km (where the unit is "km")

Currently I have done this with `StackPanel` instances everywhere. It's always the same pattern. That makes the XAML less readable than it should be.

I'm looking for a `TextBox` control that already includes that `TextBlock` at its side to display the unit.

My first try was a class derived from `TextBox`, with a XAML file that replaces the `Template` property like this:

```
<TextBox
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.UnitTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="_this"
    KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
    Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, ElementName=_this}"
                    Style="{TemplateBinding Style}"
                    Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=_this}"
                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                    ... lots more ...
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{Binding Unit, ElementName=_this}"
                    Margin="4,0,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

`Unit` is a dependency property in my `UnitTextBox` code-behind class:

```
public partial class UnitTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static DependencyProperty UnitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        name: "Unit",
        propertyType: typeof(string),
        ownerType: typeof(UnitTextBox));

    public string Unit
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(UnitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnitProperty, value); }
    }

    public UnitTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's a number of issues with this approach. I need to pass through virtually all properties to the inner `TextBox` as you can see (I abbreviated it here). Also, I'd like the `Width` property to apply to the inner `TextBox` as usual, not to the outer `Grid`. Think I need a separate property for that and bind the inner `TextBox` instance to that. And currently, the style that I set when using the `UnitTextBox` class is ignored. I don't even know how to solve that.

Is there any possibility to create such a combined control with WPF? It should act like a `TextBox` with all its event handlers, bindable properties etc., but already include that unit string in its appearance, assignable by an additional property.

Could I instead use a custom `Style` that adds the `TextBlock` somewhere around (but I think I need the outer `Grid` for aligning things), and declare the unit with an attached property?

Comment: this approach is too complex. Just create a MyUnitTextBox class derived from UserControl, and place a TextBox besides a TextBlock in a 2-column Grid.

Comment: Your scenarion by the way gives the best reason to create a UserControl to encapsulate StackPanel, TextBlock and TextBox.

Comment: And how can I access all the other TextBox events and properties through the UserControl? Or apply TextBox-targeted styles to it?

Comment: For that you usually add Dependency properties to your UserControl, to communicate with its owning elements. A textBox style would be part of the UserControl, since the TextBox belongs to the UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annoying thing about extending a templated control is that you typically need to define a new template for each system theme, or your customized `TextBox` will look out of place next to a regular `TextBox`.  However, since your "enhancement" is fairly simple, we can avoid this entirely by simply overriding the layout and rendering code to include the unit text:

```
public class UnitTextBox : TextBox
{
    private FormattedText _unitText;
    private Rect _unitTextBounds;

    public static DependencyProperty UnitTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            name: "UnitText",
            propertyType: typeof(string),
            ownerType: typeof(UnitTextBox),
            typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                default(string),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public string UnitText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UnitTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnitTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty UnitPaddingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            name: "UnitPadding",
            propertyType: typeof(Thickness),
            ownerType: typeof(UnitTextBox),
            typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new Thickness(5d, 0d, 0d, 0d),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Thickness UnitPadding
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(UnitPaddingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnitPaddingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty TextBoxWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            name: "TextBoxWidth",
            propertyType: typeof(double),
            ownerType: typeof(UnitTextBox),
            typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                double.NaN,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public double TextBoxWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TextBoxWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (e.Property == ForegroundProperty)
            EnsureUnitText(invalidate: true);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var textBoxWidth = this.TextBoxWidth;
        var unit = EnsureUnitText(invalidate: true);
        var padding = this.UnitPadding;

        if (unit != null)
        {
            var unitWidth = unit.Width + padding.Left + padding.Right;
            var unitHeight = unit.Height + padding.Top + padding.Bottom;

            constraint = new Size(
                constraint.Width - unitWidth,
                Math.Max(constraint.Height, unitHeight));
        }

        var hasFixedTextBoxWidth = !double.IsNaN(textBoxWidth) &&
                                   !double.IsInfinity(textBoxWidth);

        if (hasFixedTextBoxWidth)
            constraint = new Size(textBoxWidth, constraint.Height);

        var baseSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        var baseWidth = hasFixedTextBoxWidth ? textBoxWidth : baseSize.Width;

        if (unit != null)
        {
            var unitWidth = unit.Width + padding.Left + padding.Right;
            var unitHeight = unit.Height + padding.Top + padding.Bottom;

            return new Size(
                baseWidth + unitWidth,
                Math.Max(baseSize.Height, unitHeight));
        }

        return new Size(baseWidth, baseSize.Height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        var textSize = arrangeBounds;
        var unit = EnsureUnitText(invalidate: false);
        var padding = this.UnitPadding;

        if (unit != null)
        {
            var unitWidth = unit.Width + padding.Left + padding.Right;
            var unitHeight = unit.Height + padding.Top + padding.Bottom;

            textSize.Width -= unitWidth;

            _unitTextBounds = new Rect(
                textSize.Width + padding.Left,
                (arrangeBounds.Height - unitHeight) / 2 + padding.Top,
                textSize.Width,
                textSize.Height);
        }

        var baseSize = base.ArrangeOverride(textSize);

        if (unit != null)
        {
            var unitWidth = unit.Width + padding.Left + padding.Right;
            var unitHeight = unit.Height + padding.Top + padding.Bottom;

            return new Size(
                baseSize.Width + unitWidth,
                Math.Max(baseSize.Height, unitHeight));
        }

        return baseSize;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var unitText = EnsureUnitText(invalidate: false);
        if (unitText != null)
            drawingContext.DrawText(unitText, _unitTextBounds.Location);
    }

    private FormattedText EnsureUnitText(bool invalidate = false)
    {
        if (invalidate)
            _unitText = null;

        if (_unitText != null)
            return _unitText;

        var unit = this.UnitText;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unit))
        {
            _unitText = new FormattedText(
                unit,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                this.FlowDirection,
                new Typeface(
                    this.FontFamily,
                    this.FontStyle,
                    this.FontWeight,
                    this.FontStretch),
                this.FontSize,
                this.Foreground);
        }

        return _unitText;
    }
}
```

The `TextBoxWidth` property lets you set a fixed width for just the `TextBox`.  The behavior of `Width` remains unchanged, as it should: it governs the size of the entire control, e.g., the `TextBox` *and* the unit text.

No custom style or template is necessary.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, looks promising. I'll check it out soon.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I described, thank you! Just been playing a bit with it. If I wanted to keep the size normal and draw the unit text inside the TextBox at the right end, increasing the Padding, how would I draw the text then? The DrawText method seems to stay below the rest of the TextBox and not calling base.OnRender at all still doesn't make it disappear. (Background: The validation error template draws a rectangle around the entire control which now includes the unit text.)

Comment: Solved. I learned that OnRender can't draw over other things from the template/visual tree. So I moved the DrawText to an adorner.

Comment: Nice, adorners are one of the cooler and most underutilized features of WPF :).